# Closing one application from another in c# .net

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# project. From my application i have to close another application (Both are my own applications). Can i get the instance of first application in the second?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have to get all the process in the process array so that we will get which process is going on

```
Process []GetPArry = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process testProcess in GetPArry)
{
    string ProcessName = testProcess .ProcessName;

    ProcessName  = ProcessName .ToLower();
    if (ProcessName.CompareTo("winword") == 0)
        testProcess.Kill();
}
```

here winword is the another process or you can say  application running whom we are going to kill

Comment: Can be a good idea to exit the loop when the correct process is found.

Comment: i am agree with jgauffin , exit from loop when you got the process

Comment: ... unless you want to close ALL running instances of the app

Answer (score 4):

A modern day version in C# would look like this:

```
var processArray = Process.GetProcesses();
var process = processArray.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName == "AcroRd32");
process?.Kill();
```

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by using namedpipes

1- Use NamedPipe to send some event to close the second instance.

Answer (score 1):

100% Working
my Example Process is Notepad. i want to close/kill

`Process[] myProcList = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        foreach (Process Target in myProcList)
        {
            Target.Kill();
        }`